# Can I apply polyurethane to new engineered hardwood floors?

Tags: flooring, polyurethane, engineered-flooring

I just laid new engineered Maple 5/8in hardwood floors. They have a dull look.

Can I polyurethane them?

Comment: Do you know what, if any, finish is on them now?

Comment: Let it be known that you can poly pretty much anything... What kind of engineered?  Stapled, floating, glued?  Finish?